# Why does Firebase Firestore trigger query on one minute intervals?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am displaying the firebase logged in user and a collection of items in an Angular project backed by a firestore database. I have no requests that are setup to run every minute.

I noticed this request getting triggered on one minute intervals. This looks to me like long polling. Is this the case? How does this affect billing?

These are the requests that keep repeating every minute.

[image]

These are the request parameters that are being sent.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're observing.   Nothing should be invoked that's different than what you arranged.  Please edit the question to explain what's going on here that's different than what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for replying. @DougStevenson updated the question with more context.

Comment: My impression is that the client library shouldn't long poll.  Is your connection getting cut off by something in the middle?  A proxy?